# how to optimize query to big table

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-slow-query-log

I have a table with 18,310,298 records right now.

And next query

```
SELECT COUNT(obj_id) AS cnt
FROM
`common`.`logs`
WHERE 
`event` = '11' AND
`obj_type` = '2' AND
`region` = 'us' AND 
DATE(`date`) = DATE('20120213010502');
```

With next structure

```
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `log_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `obj_type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `obj_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `region` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`),
  KEY `event` (`event`),
  KEY `obj_type` (`obj_type`),
  KEY `region` (`region`),
  KEY `for_stat` (`event`,`obj_type`,`obj_id`,`region`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=83126347 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Logs table' |
```

and MySQL explain show the next

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------+----------+---------+-------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                  | key      | key_len | ref         | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------+----------+---------+-------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | logs  | ref  | event,obj_type,region,for_stat | for_stat | 2       | const,const | 837216 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------+----------+---------+-------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Running such query in daily peak usage time take about 5 seconds.

What can I do to make it faster ?

**UPDATED:** Regarding all comments I modified INDEX and take off DATE function in WHERE clause

```
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| logs  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | log_id      | A         |    15379109 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| logs  |          1 | event    |            1 | event       | A         |          14 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| logs  |          1 | obj_type |            1 | obj_type    | A         |          14 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| logs  |          1 | region   |            1 | region      | A         |          14 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| logs  |          1 | for_stat |            1 | event       | A         |         157 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| logs  |          1 | for_stat |            2 | obj_type    | A         |         157 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| logs  |          1 | for_stat |            3 | region      | A         |         157 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| logs  |          1 | for_stat |            4 | date        | A         |         157 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+


    mysql> explain extended SELECT COUNT(obj_id) as cnt 
    ->     FROM `common`.`logs` 
    ->     WHERE `event`= '11' AND 
    ->     `obj_type` = '2' AND 
    ->     `region`= 'est' AND 
    ->     date between '2012-11-25 00:00:00' and '2012-11-25 23:59:59';
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                  | key      | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | logs  | range | event,obj_type,region,for_stat | for_stat | 21      | NULL | 9674 |    75.01 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

It seems it's running faster. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Using functions in `WHERE` clause is a real performance killer. Avoid the `DATE` cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Joni already explained what is wrong with your index. For query, I assume that your example query selects all records for `2012-02-13` regardless of time. You can change the where clause to use `>=` and `<` instead of `DATE` cast:

```
SELECT COUNT(obj_id) AS cnt
FROM
`common`.`logs`
WHERE 
`event` = 11 AND
`obj_type` = 2 AND
`region` = 'us' AND 
`date` >= DATE('20120213010502') AND
`date` <  DATE('20120213010502') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 2):

The EXPLAIN output shows that the query is using only the first two columns of the `for_stat` index.

This is because the query doesn't use `obj_id` in the WHERE clause. If you create a new key without `obj_id` (or modify the existing key to reorder the columns), more of the key can be used and you may see better performance:

```
KEY `for_stat2` (`event`,`obj_type`,`region`,`date`)
```

If it's still too slow, changing the last condition, where you use `DATE()`, as said by Salman and Sashi, might improve things.

Comment: +1. Add this index and simply change the `COUNT(obj_id)` to `COUNT(*)`. `obj_id` is not nullable so the results will be identical.

Comment: @joni What about number of indexs in logs table ? in each insert update ALL indexes will be rebuilded ?

Comment: @user1016265 Indexes have to be updated (not rebuilt) when new data is inserted, so they will make `INSERT`s slower, but you need indexes if you want reasonable performance from `SELECT`s. You have to choose which is more important for you.

Answer (score 0):

The date function on the `date` column is making the full table scan.
Try this ::

```
SELECT COUNT(obj_id) as cnt
                FROM
                    `common`.`logs` 
                WHERE 
                    `event`      = 11
                AND
                    `obj_type`   = 2

                AND
                    `region`     = 'us'
                AND
                    `date` = DATE('20120213010502')
```

Comment: but I need exactly date not date + time, it means I have to use BETWEEN in last DATE condition, instead of using date function ?

Comment: @user1016265: Yes you can use the between, to get the use the date field directly, you can refer Salman's answer for the between clause, and please paste the explain plan with the updated query

Answer (score 0):

As logging (inserts) needs to be fast too, use as less indices as possible.

Evaluation may take long as that is admin, not necessarily needing indices.

```
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `log_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `obj_type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `obj_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `region` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`),
  KEY `for_stat` (`event`,`obj_type`,`region`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=83126347 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Logs table' |
```

And about the date search @SashiKant and @SalmanA already answered.

Answer (score 0):

Is Mysql you should place index columns by collation count; less possible values in table - placed closer to the left.
Also you can try to change column `region` to enum() and try to search `date` with `BETWEEN` clause. 
Mysql is not using third column in the index because it's usage takes more efforts then just filtering (it's a common thing in Mysql).